# Get the html charset from a site - Meta tags in a NON UTF-8 format

Tags: php, html, web-scraping

I try to retrieve the encoding that is encapsulated in the

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-7">
```

of an html website.

On the given html above I want to extract the "iso-8859-7" part do you know how I can do that?

Note: that it can be any sort of value.

I need it because sometimes I will need the site's Encoding in order to retrieve the meta tags and encode it properly.

Note: That I have already retrieved the content of the html via php Curl or file_get_contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you receive that in a string? If so, you can just use RegEx to retrieve it.

```
$string = '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-7">'; // your string

$matches = array(); 
preg_match('/charset=[^"]*/', $string, $matches); // retrieve charset and the value
preg_replace('/charset=/', '', $matches[0]); // remove the 'charset='
```

You will get the value as a string. If you have the html file to begin with the previous answer should help.

EDIT:
if you want to learn more about ReGex, you can read this:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_regular_expression.htm

For what I did; I simply request "charset=" and everthing that follows which is not a quotation mark. [^"]*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery

If you have only a meta then you can get this way

```
var myValue = $('head meta').get(0).attr("content");
```

or if you have several

```
$("head meta").each(function () {
  alert( $(this).attr("content");
});
```

in PHP you can use

> $tags = get_meta_tags('http://www.example.com/');
>
> ```
>  echo $tags['author'];       // name
>  echo $tags['keywords'];     // php documentation
>  echo $tags['description'];  // a php manual
>  echo $tags['geo_position']; // 49.33;-86.59
> ```

this is from http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php  PHP DOC

Comment: has not a different you can use @scaisEdge answer in php

Comment: I have anyway update the answer with a suggetion PHP based

Comment: The problem is that I get it in wrong ancoding and the get_meta_tags does not retrieve it with "Content-Type"

Comment: could be there BOM at the begin